# PyInstaller not working with module pycountry?

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

Normally PyInstaller works fine for me but i saw a problem using the python-module pycountry.

I tried this very simple code:

```
import pycountry
land="DE"
country = pycountry.countries.get (alpha_2=land)
print(country.name)
```

Compiled it with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile xyz.py
```

But i want to execute the compiled exe i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycountry
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pycountry\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pycountry' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[45548] Failed to execute script temp2
```

Is there any workaround i can get pycountry functionality to running with pyinstaller?

UPDATE:
found a workaround / solution for my problem-

1. use command <pyi-makespec --onefile temp2.py> to generate a temp2.spec file
2. change filename.spec => from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata (in the header) => in the a = Analysis(...) section change " datas = []," to <datas = copy_metadata("pycountry"),>
3. use pyinstaller to compile exe as above

Alternative: compile program before - change spec - an use command <pyInstaller --clean temp2.spec> – Rapid1898 just now   Edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update was really helpful to me. But I needed a variation in order for it to work. I would just order the ideas to show clearer the way it must be done for pycountry library to work properly.

1. Use command `pyi-makespec --onefile name-of-your-file.py` to generate a .spec file
   with name name-of-your-file.spec
2. Open name-of-your-file.spec with the text editor of your preference.

   - Add to the top of the .spec file the following line `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata`
   - Replace `datas = []` for `datas = copy_metadata("pycountry")`
3. Then rebuild using the following command `PyInstaller --clean name-of-your-file.spec`

I hope it is helpful for anyone facing the same error.

You can read the documentation for [using spec files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles).

And you can find the same process in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/pyinstaller/OYhJdeZ9010).